# Show that a complete graph with m edges has (1+8m)/2 vertices.

Tags: combinatorics

Hello I don't understand how this works. I thought a graph with n edges has 
n(n-1)/2 vertices. Also when I put in numbers for m I get a fraction answer. Does that mean that m is fraction to begin with but that doesn't make sense since m is the number of edges.  Please help

Answer (score 2):

I think you misread the formula.

Suppose there are $n$ vertices.

Then each vertex is connected
to $n-1$ vertices
for a total of
$n(n-1)$ edges.

However,
since this counts each edge twice,
the total number of edges is
$\frac12n(n-1)$.

If there are $m$ edges,
then
$m
=\frac12n(n-1)
$,
so
$n(n-1)=2m$
or
$n^2-n-2m = 0$.

Solving this quadratic equation,
$n
=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}
$.

Since $n > 0$,
we must have
$n
=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}
$.

And *this*,
I think,
is the formula you meant.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A complete graph with $n$ vertices has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges *only if it undirected*. Otherwise, it has $n(n-1)$ edges.